# preventing extreme memory usage

Tags: memory, raku

my script works on a line by line basis. The task per line implies use of a Grammar, but is not too complicated. I notice that when the input has a lot of lines, say 150_000, the memory usage is gigantic, over 6G, and my computer hangs. I used --profile on shorter input, but that gives me no clue where to look for a solution. Most names in there do not refer to my code. 
Any suggestions on where I can prevent spurious memory use or find out what is causing this?

here is the core loop:

```
method process() {
    my $promise = Promise.start({
      &!start-handler();
      my $intro = 1; # to skip the directory part of the file.
      for $!source-name.IO.lines {
        ...
      }
    }).then({ $!DB.completed });
    await $promise;
  }
```

Thanks,
Theo

Comment: Have you tried running that code with a basically nothing where the `...` is? Does it have the same memory effect? If not then I would guess it's the code you're not showing us.

Comment: @Scimon I don't think that is very useful. I am already sure it is something in there. I just don't know where to look. I see nothing suspicious. I will try and binary search my way into the code. BTW, I have been using this code months without problems.

Comment: Just trying to help. Sorry if it didn't come across well.

Comment: @Scimon, sorry, it was me who came across wrong. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I find that my code is particularly impeded by this line

$formula ~~ m:g/ << $<funname>=<[A..Z]>+  '(' <{ %fun{$<funname>}++ }> /;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found one thing that caused havoc. By changing the line

```
m:g/ << $<funname>=<[A..Z]>+ '(' <{ %fun{$<funname>}++ }> /;
```

by something like

```
 if $formula ~~ m:g/ << $<funname>=<[A..Z]>+  '(' / {
        for $/.list -> $funname {
          %fun{$<funname>}++
        };
      }
```

the script gets a zillion times faster and runs without problems.

However, see @JonathanWorthington's reaction below. My conclusion:
I should have used:

```
m:g/ << $<funname>=<[A..Z]>+ '(' { %fun{$<funname>}++ } /;
```

Again, this used to work in previous editions of rakudo.
This is Rakudo version 2020.01 built on MoarVM version 2020.01.1
implementing Perl 6.d.

Comment: `<{ %fun{$<funname>}++ }>` will `EVAL` what is returned from the block as a regex. Probably just `{ %fun{$<funname>}++ }` (without the angles around it) is what was wanted.

Comment: @JonathanWorthington. Brilliant! I missed that completely. This is the best answer.